# Linux shellscripting

Tags: linux, shell

I'm running a utility script as below

./myscript -d myhomedir

this throws an output as below
Info: creating a the files in a above mentioned homedir

Enter Password:

I want this password to be an input from a file which I have encoded in a base64 format 
here is my script

```
passwd=`cat ${myhomedir}/.passwd`
deCrypt=`openssl enc -base64 -d <<< $passwd`
echo $deCrypt
./myscript -d myhomedir
expect "Enter Password:"
send -- "$deCrypt"
```

This isn't working. please could anyone guide me if there a way where we can read the password from a file and take it as an input? without typing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho ./myscript -d myhomedir
expect -re "Enter Password" { send -- [exec cat ~/.passwd | openssl enc -base64 -d ]\r }
interact

puts "\nDone.\n"
exit
```